# Error passing in parameters Android Web Service login?

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl

I have written an app to login in via a WSDL. I am having trouble where I try to pass in certain parameters and am stuck. I have looked at similar questions here but none seem to be having the issue I am even if they are doing this in a similar way. Here is my code, I have commented in my errors:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


    public class WebService {
    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
    private static String URL = "http://84.51.246.251/ttms/remoteaccess.asmx?WSDL";
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://84.51.246.251/ttms/remoteaccess.asmx";

    public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String userName,String passWord, String webMethName) {
        boolean loginStatus = false;
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Username, error:The method setName(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        unamePI.setName("username");
        // Set Value, error:The method setValue(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        unamePI.setValue(userName);
        // Set dataType, error:The method setType(Class<String>) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        unamePI.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object, error:The method addProperty(PropertyInfo, Object) in the type SoapObject is not applicable for the arguments (PropertyInfo)
        request.addProperty(unamePI);
        PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
        //Set Password, error:The method setName(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        passPI.setName("password");
        //Set dataType, error The method setValue(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        passPI.setValue(passWord);
        //Set dataType, errorThe method setType(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo
        passPI.setType(String.class);
        //Add the property to request object, errorThe method addProperty(PropertyInfo, Object) in the type SoapObject is not applicable for the arguments (PropertyInfo) 
        request.addProperty(passPI);
        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
            loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            CheckLoginActivity.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //Return booleam to calling object
        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: URL is correct? Please confirm it once.

Comment: Hi yes it is correct in my project, I just changed it when posting on here

Comment: Post the correct one, then I can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an AsyncTask like this

```
private class GetAuthentication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

       private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
    private static String URL = "http://84.51.246.251/ttms/remoteaccess.asmx?WSDL";
    ProgressDialog pd ;
    private Context _context;

   public GetAuthentication(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }



    protected void onPreExecute ()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
        pd.setTitle("Processing");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }




 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (params[0].trim().equals(""))
    return "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, params[0]);  

    request.addProperty("userName", params[1]);
    request.addProperty("password", params[2]);

  // params[0] --> function name that you have passed from activity
  // params[1] --> username name that you have passed from activity
  // params[2] --> password that you have passed from activity


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + params[0], envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        return response.toString();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
        return "Error";
    }

}


protected void onPostExecute(String str)
{
    super.onPostExecute(str);
    try
    {
        if (pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Error"))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again after some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else
    {

       // here parse your json or whatever you are retrieving from the server
    }
}
```

Call like this from your activity :

```
new GetAuthentication(your_activity.this).execute("RemoteLogin", user_name, pwd);
```

First parameter --> the function name, second --> username (maybe fetched from edittext), third --> password (maybe fetched from edittext)

**EDIT : If you are getting the username and password from EditTexts**

On click of login

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              String user_Name = ed_txtName.getText().toString();
              String user_Pwd = ed_txtPassword.getText().toString();
              new GetAuthentication(your_activity.this).execute("RemoteLogin", user_Name, user_Pwd);

        }
    });
```

`ed_txtName` and `ed_txtPassword` are EditTexts and `login` is the Button

**Complete Code**

**main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_Pwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Password"
         android:padding="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
   private EditText txtName, txtPassword;
private Button login;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);





    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Pwd);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);



login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 userName = txtName.getText().toString();
                 userPwd = txtPassword.getText().toString();

                if (userName.trim().equals(""))
                    txtName.setError("Please enter username");
                if (userPwd.trim().equals(""))
                    txtPassword.setError("Please enter password");
                if (!userName.trim().equals("") && !userPwd.trim().equals(""))
                {

                    new GetAuthentication(MainActivity.this).execute("RemoteLogin",userName, userPwd);
                }



            }
        });
    }



 private class GetAuthentication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {

           private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        //Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
        private static String URL = "http://84.51.246.251/ttms/remoteaccess.asmx?WSDL";
        ProgressDialog pd ;
        private Context _context;

       public GetAuthentication(Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }



        protected void onPreExecute ()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            pd.setTitle("Processing");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }




     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (params[0].trim().equals(""))
        return "";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, params[0]);  

        request.addProperty("userName", params[1]);
        request.addProperty("password", params[2]);

      // params[0] --> function name that you have passed from activity
      // params[1] --> username name that you have passed from activity
      // params[2] --> password that you have passed from activity


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + params[0], envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            return response.toString();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
            return "Error";
        }

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String str)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(str);
        try
        {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Error"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again after some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else
        {

           // here parse your json or whatever you are retrieving from the server
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For function name that would be RemoteLogin as this is the SOAP_ACTION? Also for username and password if I am getting it from user in the GUI what should I say for param 1 and 2?

Comment: I'm not using soap_action variable, please check carefully. See my edit.

Comment: Ok I see, if I do want to take in the params 1 and 2 from user how should I do this? Also for getApplicationContext() do I have to create this method somewhere else? THanks

Comment: It is just the getApplicationContext() where I have an error, how should I create this? And take in params from user? also for the else where you say // here parse your json or whatever you are retrieving from the server, is this whats meant to happen if login is successful?

Comment: Yeah, that is where you get the information from web service. If getApplicationContext is giving error then delete that line. Your main class should be extending `Activity`, then you will not get that error. Otherwise post your complete modified code again in the question. Or create it in separate thread and give me the link here.

Comment: Apologies for being so slow to this. So the activity I already have WebService change it to extend activity, then create the new class GetAuthentication. Then add login.setOnClickListener part to my existing class WebService?

Comment: Seems like you are very naive. It's ok. I will post the entire code.

Comment: Yes I am very new to web services, and struggling! Thank you

Comment: Please let me know when posted.

Comment: If I want to go to a new activity if logged in correctly(eg startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));) where would I put this?

Comment: Where do you get to know that login is successful? In which method?

Comment: If the web service completes this means it's logged in doesnt it?

Comment: That depends on what is coming back from server.